# Одинаковые объекты добавляются в Set

Tags: java, сериализация, equals, hashset

Столкнулся со странной проблемой возможности добавления в Set одинаковых объектов (equals и hashSet переопределены) после сериализации. Расскажу по порядку.

- Создаю объект
- Добавляю его в Set
- Создаю точно такой же объект
- Добавляю в Set, он не добавляется, что и следовало ожидать так как они равны.
- Сереализую объект из сета
- Десереализую этот же объект и добавляю в Set и он (!) добавляется

Теперь у меня во множестве два объекта причем если их сравнить то метод equals выдает true.

Как такое может быть?

Добавлю задачу которую решаю.

Я создаю различные объекты (машины с разной конфигурацией) после этого добавляю их во множество по одному и прикаждом добавлении я сереализую все элементы множества в файл.
При вызове toString я десереализую объекты из файла, для этого и выбрал множество что бы самому не приходилось каждый раз их сравнивать и быть уверенным что даже если у меня там есть одинаковые объекты то Set их не пропустит.

Создание файла:

```
private String dirForFile = "./files";

private String fileForSave = "/Garage.ser";

private Path mkDir = Paths.get(dirForFile);

private Path mkFile = Paths.get(dirForFile, fileForSave);

private void createFile() {
        try {
            if (!Files.isDirectory(mkDir)) {
                Files.createDirectory(mkDir);
                System.out.println("mkdir");
            }           
            if (!Files.exists(mkFile)) {
                Files.createFile(mkFile);
                System.out.println("mkfile");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
```

Сереализация:

```
private Set<Vehicule> voitures = new LinkedHashSet<>(); 

public void saveAllObjToFile() {
        createFile();
        try (ObjectOutputStream objToSave = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(mkFile.toFile())))) {
            for (Vehicule vhl : voitures) {
                objToSave.writeObject(vhl);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem with save all objects in the file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Десериализация:

```
private void loadObjFromFile() {
    try (ObjectInputStream objToLoad = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(mkFile.toFile())))) {
        while (true) {
            voitures.add((Vehicule) objToLoad.readObject());
        }
    } catch (EOFException e2) {

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Класс Vehicule:

```
package fr.kacetal.vehicule;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import fr.kacetal.moteur.*;
import fr.kacetal.option.*;

public abstract class Vehicule implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1548507637332494726L;

    private BigDecimal prix = new BigDecimal("0.0").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

    private Set<Option> options = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    private String nom = "";    

    private Marque marque;

    private Moteur moteur;

    protected Vehicule(String nom, Marque marque) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.marque = marque;
    }

    public void setMoteur(Moteur moteur) {
        this.moteur = moteur;
    }

    public void addOption(final Option option) {
        options.add(option);
    }

    private BigDecimal getPrix() {
        prix = new BigDecimal("0.0").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        if (!options.isEmpty()) {
            for (Option option : options) {
                prix = prix.add(option.getPrix());
            }
        }
        if (!(moteur == null)) {
            prix = prix.add(moteur.getPrix());
        }

        return prix;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Voiture ").append(marque);
        sb.append(" : ").append(nom);
        sb.append(" ").append(moteur);
        sb.append(" ").append(options);
        sb.append(" d'une valeur totale de " + getPrix().toString() + "\u20AC");

        return sb.toString();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((marque == null) ? 0 : marque.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((moteur == null) ? 0 : moteur.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((nom == null) ? 0 : nom.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((options == null) ? 0 : options.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((prix == null) ? 0 : prix.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Vehicule)) {
            return false;
        }
        Vehicule other = (Vehicule) obj;
        if (marque != other.marque) {
            return false;
        }
        if (moteur == null) {
            if (other.moteur != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!moteur.equals(other.moteur)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (nom == null) {
            if (other.nom != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!nom.equals(other.nom)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (options == null) {
            if (other.options != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!options.equals(other.options)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (prix == null) {
            if (other.prix != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (prix.compareTo(other.prix) != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Создал класс для теста.

```
package fr.kacetal;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;
import fr.kacetal.moteur.*;
import fr.kacetal.option.*;
import fr.kacetal.vehicule.*;

public class MainTest {

    private static String dirForFile = "./files";

    private static String fileForSave = "/Garage.ser";

    private static Path mkDir = Paths.get(dirForFile);

    private static Path mkFile = Paths.get(dirForFile, fileForSave);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vehicule lag1 = new Lagouna();
        lag1.setMoteur(new MoteurEssence("150 Chevaux", "10256"));
        lag1.addOption(new GPS());
        lag1.addOption(new SiegeChauffant());
        lag1.addOption(new VitreElectrique());

        Vehicule lag2 = new Lagouna();
        lag2.setMoteur(new MoteurEssence("150 Chevaux", "10256"));
        lag2.addOption(new GPS());
        lag2.addOption(new SiegeChauffant());
        lag2.addOption(new VitreElectrique());

        HashSet<Vehicule> vSet = new HashSet<>();
        vSet.add(lag1);
        vSet.add(lag2);
        System.out.println(vSet);

        try {
            if (!Files.isDirectory(mkDir)) {
                Files.createDirectory(mkDir);
                System.out.println("mkdir");
            }           
            if (!Files.exists(mkFile)) {
                Files.createFile(mkFile);
                System.out.println("mkfile");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (ObjectOutputStream objToSave = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(mkFile.toFile(), false)))) {
            for (Vehicule vhl : vSet) {
                objToSave.writeObject(vhl);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem with save all objects in the file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (ObjectInputStream objToLoad = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(mkFile.toFile())))) {
            while (true) {
                vSet.add((Vehicule) objToLoad.readObject());
            }
        } catch (EOFException e2) {

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(vSet.size());

        Vehicule[] v1 = new Vehicule[2];
        int i = 0;
        for (Vehicule vehicule : vSet) {
            v1[i++] = vehicule;
            System.out.println(vehicule.hashCode());

        }
        System.out.println(v1[0].equals(v1[1]));
        System.out.println(vSet);
    }
}
```

Вывод консоли

```
[Voiture Reneault : Lagouna Moteur ESSENCE 150 Chevaux (10256€) [GPS (113.5€), Siège chauffant (562.9€), Vitre electrique (212.35€)] d'une valeur totale de 11144.75€]
2
-1472721326
-1472721326
true
[Voiture Reneault : Lagouna Moteur ESSENCE 150 Chevaux (10256€) [GPS (113.5€), Siège chauffant (562.9€), Vitre electrique (212.35€)] d'une valeur totale de 11144.75€, Voiture Reneault : Lagouna Moteur ESSENCE 150 Chevaux (10256€) [GPS (113.5€), Siège chauffant (562.9€), Vitre electrique (212.35€)] d'une valeur totale de 11144.75€]
```

Как видно, в конце объектов два и Хеш коды у них равны.

PS: Если честно то бьюсь головой об эту проблему уже третий день и сейчас мне приходит мысль что может проще было бы сереализовать все множество целиком и при десереализации просто его перезаписывать, но хотелось бы  все таки понять в чем проблема.

Comment: стоит еще добавить пример реализации `equals` и других методов. А так же как создаешь второй элемент сам, и как сериализуешь/десериализуешь

Comment: Сравните значения `equals()` и `hashSet()` у исходного и десериализованного объектов. Похоже, что они разные.

Comment: После десериализации у меня Set двумя с элементами, hashSet выдает одинаковые значения, equals выдает true.

Comment: Примеров кода вас просят в вопрос добавить

Comment: И еще реализацию класса `Vehicule` и пример как ты заполняешь эту коллекцию - один два объекта

Comment: Попробуй либо добавить логи в методы equals и hashCode чтобы узнать в каком именно месте и почему возвращается `false`, либо воспользуйся отладчиком и пройди этот путь по шагам

Answer (score 4, accepted):

возможно один или больше классов опций не переопределяют equals, а следовательно их (непустые) множества при сравнении дают отрицательный результат.

Попробуйте добавить в тест следующее (попутно проапгрейдив тест до JUnit или TestNG)

```
assertEquals(new GPS(), new GPS());
assertEquals(new SiegeChauffant(), new SiegeChauffant());
assertEquals(new VitreElectrique(), new VitreElectrique());
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем переписал большую часть кода заново и все заработало. Методы equals и hashCod были переопределены изначально и их я сильно не менял, единственное что было добавлено, из значимых изменений, это конструктор без параметров в абстрактные классы от которых происходит наследование (вроде это нужно при десереализации). Но если честно в итоге я так и не разобрался почему у меня получалось закинуть в коллекцию два объекта которые имели одинаковый хэш и выдавали true в функции equals.

Код скинул на github:
https://github.com/kacetal/Garage